# stringRounds is Looping, Rejecting Valid Value

Tags: java, string, loops, netbeans, while-loop

The loop is working when I enter invalid values, but it still shows the same message when I enter a Valid value. Please help.

```
public class RockPaperScissors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rnd = new Random();
    
        String stringRounds = " ";
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper Scissors!");
        System.out.println("Let's begin with the number of rounds you would like to play: " );
        stringRounds = sc.nextLine();  
        
        int rounds = Integer.parseInt(stringRounds);
        
        while (rounds < 1 || rounds > 10) {
            System.out.println(stringRounds + (" is out of my range. Please try again."));
            stringRounds = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(stringRounds +(" sounds good to me. Let's Get Started!!"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't update the value of rounds in the while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rnd = new Random();
    
        String stringRounds = " ";
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper Scissors!");
        System.out.println("Let's begin with the number of rounds you would like to play: " );
        stringRounds = sc.nextLine();  
        
        int rounds = Integer.parseInt(stringRounds);
        
        while (rounds < 1 || rounds > 10) {
            System.out.println(stringRounds + (" is out of my range. Please try again."));
            stringRounds = sc.nextLine();
            rounds=  Integer.parseInt(stringRounds);//add this row
        }
        System.out.println(stringRounds +(" sounds good to me. Let's Get Started!!"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a condition on `rounds` in the while loop, but you do not modify its value.

Also, you should declare your new Random() when you need it, and I suggest you to use Random.nextInt(n) instead, it's less predictable.

Last thing, why use a String for the user choice ? You need to parse it ... You should use int instead.

Comment: its an assignment where we have to use stuff that we learned from class. Instructor went over Java basics in less than a week. Doing Library Applications already

Comment: Change sc.nextLine() to sc.nextInt() in order to save the user choice in a int variable so you don't need to parse it, good luck !